# Поправить выпадающий список

Tags: javascript, html, html5, search

нужно что бы когда я начинаю вводить в поле город - в подсказке всплывали не все, а только начинающиеся на введенную букву

если введена А - показываются армавир и абакан

```html
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">
var autocomplete = ['абакан', 'армавир', 'баку', 'биробиджан', 'вильнюс'];
window.onload = function() {
 document.getElementById('input').onkeyup = keyUp;
}
function keyUp(e) {
 var e = e||window.event;
 switch(e.keyCode) {
  case 40:
   var selected = -1;
   var spans = document.getElementById('autocomplete').getElementsByTagName('span');
   for(i=0;i<=spans.length;i++)
    if (i in spans && spans[i].className == 'selected') {
     spans[i].className = '';
     selected = i;
    }
   selected++;
   for(i=0;i<=spans.length;i++)
    if (i in spans && i == selected) {
     spans[i].className = 'selected';
    }
   break;
  case 38: 
   var spans = document.getElementById('autocomplete').getElementsByTagName('span');
   var selected = spans.length;
   for(i=0;i<=spans.length;i++)
    if (i in spans && spans[i].className == 'selected') {
     spans[i].className = '';
     selected = i;
    }
   selected--;
   for(i=0;i<=spans.length;i++)
    if (i in spans && i == selected) {
     spans[i].className = 'selected';
    }
   break;
  case 13: 
   var spans = document.getElementById('autocomplete').getElementsByTagName('span');
   for(i=0;i<=spans.length;i++)
    if (i in spans && spans[i].className == 'selected') {
     document.getElementById('input').value = spans[i].innerHTML;
     document.getElementById('autocomplete').innerHTML = '';
    }
   break;
  default: 
   var div = document.getElementById('autocomplete');
   div.innerHTML = '';
   if (document.getElementById('input').value.length > 0) {
    autocomplete.forEach(function(elem, index) {
     div.innerHTML += '<span>'+autocomplete[index]+'</span><br />';
    });
   }
 }
}
</script>
<style>
input {
 position: absolute;
 top: 10px;
 left: 150px;
}

#autocomplete {
 position: absolute;
 top: 40px;
 left: 150px;
}

span.selected {
 background-color: red;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
<input type="text" id="input" />
<div id="autocomplete"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Если в велосипедостроении нет особой необходимости, можно воспользоваться готовым: https://select2.org/getting-started/basic-usage

Comment: спасибо, но у них ни один пример не работает,

Comment: <head>
    <link href="css/select2.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <script src="js/select2.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<select class="js-example-basic-multiple" name="states[]" multiple="multiple">
    <option value="AL">Alabama</option>
    <option value="WY">Wyoming</option>
</select>
<script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $('.js-example-basic-multiple').select2();
    });
</script>

Comment: выдает квадратик с 2 штатами и икакого поиска

Comment: проверьте консоль, мне кажется у Вас jQuery не установлен. `$(document).ready(function() { $('.js-example-basic-multiple').select2(); });` Эта строчка не выполнится без jQuery.

Comment: @AlexandrSysoev а где вы увидели document ready function ?

Comment: @МаксимЛенский два комментария выше.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Привет, да поможет тебе RegEx. Ну или попроще: elem.includes(value). Смотри [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/timatru/t9a4y64y/3/)

```
    default: 
        var div = document.getElementById('autocomplete');
        var value = document.getElementById('input').value;
        div.innerHTML = '';
        if (value.length > 0) {
            autocomplete.forEach(function(elem, index) {
                var regex = new RegExp("^" + value, "i");
                if(elem.match(regex)) div.innerHTML += '<span>'+autocomplete[index]+'</span><br />';
            });
        }
```